Abelian group structure of $MU^*(BC_{p})$
Let $p$ be a prime and let $C_p$ be a cyclic group of order $p$. What is the explicit description of the abelian groups $MU^*(BC_p)$, where $MU^*$ denotes complex cobordism? I know that there is an explicit ring description using the formal group law:
$$MU^*(\mathrm{pt})[[x]]/([p]\cdot x)$$
where $x$ carries degree 2 (c.f. Section 4 of Quillen's paper "Elementary proofs of some results of cobordism theory using Steenrod operations"). However, understanding the abelian group structure of this quotient explicitly does not seem entirely straightforward. For example, is there torsion?

The paper Brown–Peterson cohomology from Morava $K$-theory (by Ravenel, Wilson and Yagita) shows that if $X$ is a space with $K(n)^*(X)$ concentrated in even degrees for all $n$ then $BP^*(X)$ is also concentrated in even degrees and is Landweber exact (and in particular, torsion free).  This statement implicitly depends on a prime $p$; if it holds for all $p$, then $MU^*(X)$ will also be concentrated in even degrees and torsion-free and Landweber exact.  In particular, this applies when $X=BA$ for any finite abelian group $A$.
Beyond that, I do not think that there is anything very useful to say about the abelian group structure.  It is not very easy to even formulate good questions or answers about infinitely-generated abelian groups of this type.  For most applications where you might be tempted to use $BP^*(BG)$, it is better to try to use $\widehat{E(n)}^*(BG)$ instead.  It is known that the $p$-completion of $BP$ is a retract of $\prod_nL_{K(n)}BP$ (Theorem 3.1 of Bousfield Localization Functors and Hopkins’ Chromatic Splitting Conjecture by Hovey) and that $L_{K(n)}BP$ is a the $K(n)$-localisation of a direct sum of spectra of the form $\Sigma^{2d}\widehat{E(n)}$ (Theorem B of Invertible spectra in the $E(n)$-local stable homotopy category by Hovey and Sadofsky), so many questions about $BP$ can be reduced to questions about $\widehat{E(n)}$.

Thank you for your answer. Where should I look to learn more about the statement that $L_{K(n)}BP$ is the $K(n)$-localisation of a direct sum of shifts of $\widehat{E(n)}$?

@onefishtwofish I have added references.
